# What is the Linux equivalent to MAXDWORD?

Tags: c++, linux, constants

In Microsoft Visual C++, there is a constant called MAXDWORD defined in winnt.h as follows:

> #define MAXDWORD 0xffffffff

It's useful as a high initial value for a 'double' when one is searching for the lowest value in a collection.
Google though I might, I can't find the equivalent in standard headers on Linux, but I'm willing to bet there must be one.

I'm using:

- uBuntu 10.04 64bit
- g++ 4.4.3

Comment: While answers below are correct wouldn't positive infinity be better initial value or at least `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Standard solution is to use [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits). For instance, `std::numeric_limits<long>::max()`. You could use any standard type instead of `long` there. You even can to specialize `numeric_limits` for custom types.

Comment: It's just an example. You could put there whatever you want.

Comment: perfect, that's just what I need!

Answer (score 3):

```
#  define UINT_MAX  4294967295U
```

Found in [`/usr/include/limits.h`](http://compute.cnr.berkeley.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?limits.h+3)